# Making a variable non-inheritable in python

Tags: python, inheritance

Is there a way to make a variable non-inheritable in python? Like in the following example: B is a subclass of A, but I want it to have its own SIZE value.

Could I get an Error to be raised (on __init__ or on getsize()) if B doesn't override SIZE?

```
class A:
   SIZE = 5
   def getsize(self): return self.SIZE

class B(A): pass
```

**Edit**: ... while inheriting the getsize() method...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to make *absolutely* sure that subclasses of `A` override `SIZE`, you could use a metaclass for `A` that will raise an error when a subclass does not override it (note that `A` is a new-style class here):

```
class ClassWithSize(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        if 'SIZE' not in attrs:
            raise NotImplementedError('The "%s" class does not implement a "SIZE" attribute' % name)
        super(ClassWithSize, cls).__init__(name, bases, attrs)

class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = ClassWithSize

    SIZE = 5
    def getsize(self):
        return self.SIZE

class B(A):
    SIZE = 6

class C(A):
    pass
```

When you put the above in a module and attempt to import it, an exception will be raised when the import reaches the `C` class implementation.

Comment: Thanks!
I see... This should do the job, but it doesn't look particularly elegant...

Comment: So what you wanted is to enforce that subclasses set their own value for the class attribute and not allow them to delegate to the value set by class A?

Comment: Yeah, I must admit it's kind of hackish, messing with metaclasses has this eerie, black magic aura about it

Comment: @Emma: it doesn't look elegant because -- generally -- it's not necessary.  We're all adults.  Simply look at the subclass code and be sure it overrides SIZE.  Much simpler and more elegant to look at the code.

Comment: @S.Lott Thanks! In my case there are lots of subclasses to check, that is why I didn't want to go through the code and check manually.

Answer (score 8):

Use a double-underscore prefix:

(Double-underscore solution deleted after Emma's clarification)

OK, you can do it like this:

```
class A:
    SIZE = 5
    def __init__(self):
        if self.__class__ != A:
            del self.SIZE

    def getsize(self):
        return self.SIZE

class B(A):
    pass

a = A()
print a.getsize()
# Prints 5

b = B()
print b.getsize()
# AttributeError: B instance has no attribute 'SIZE'
```

Comment: I wanted to inherit the method, but not the variable. It would be weird to copy and paste the same method to all the subclasses :(

Comment: ... But then, even if I specify SIZE in B, it still raises the same AttributeError: B instance has no attribute 'SIZE'.

Comment: I guess there's just no elegant way to do it. Steef's solution works, but it looks kinda ...mmm... hacky.

Comment: @RichieHindle  
In your example class B does not need its own __init__ method.  The code: b=B() calls the one from A anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If metaclasses scare you (and I sympathize with that attitude!-), a descriptor could work -- you don't even have to make your custom descriptor (though that's [easy](http://users.rcn.com/python/download/Descriptor.htm) enough), a plain good old property could work fine too:

```
class A(object):

  @property
  def SIZE(self):
    if type(self) is not A:
      raise AttributeError("Class %s MUST explicitly define SIZE!" % 
                            type(self).__name__)

  def getsize(self):
    return self.SIZE
```

Of course, this way you'll get the error only when an instance of a subclass of A which doesn't override SIZE actually tries to *use* `self.SIZE` (the metaclass approach has the advantage of giving the error earlier, when an errant subclass of A is created).

Answer (score 1):

The only approach that I can add is to use `hasattr(self.__class__, 'SIZE')` in the implementation of `getsize()` and toss an exception if the attribute is not found. Something like:

```
class A:
   SIZE = 5
   def getsize(self):
     klass = self.__class__
     if hasattr(klass, 'SIZE') and 'SIZE' in klass.__dict__:
       return self.SIZE
     raise NotImplementedError('SIZE is not defined in ' + klass.__name__)
```

There is some magic still missing since the derived class could define a method named `SIZE` and `getsize` wouldn't detect it. You can probably do some `type(klass.SIZE)` magic to filter this out if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

You can always just override it like this:

```
class B(A):  
  SIZE = 6
```

Comment: I just want to make sure that all subclasses of A override it. (That there is no way they can inherit the variable)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is a private variable.  In which case this is what you need to do:

```
class A:
    __SIZE = 5
    def getsize(self): 
        return self.__SIZE

    def setsize(self,newsize):
        self.__SIZE=newsize

class B(A): 
    pass
```

Comment: Hi Mark,
No, that's not what I want.
With your code,
b = B()
print b.getsize() # prints 5
I don't want B to be able to access the __SIZE variable in A.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach might be to get classes A and B to inherit from a third class instead of one from the other:

```
class X:
    def getsize(self):
        return self.SIZE
class A(X):
    SIZE = 5

class B(X): pass

a = A()
print a.getsize()
# Prints 5

b = B()
print b.getsize()
# AttributeError: B instance has no attribute 'SIZE'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another common idiom is to use [NotImplemented](http://docs.python.org/library/constants.html?highlight=notimplemented#NotImplemented).  Think of it as the middle ground between metaclass enforcement and mere documentation.

```
class A:
   SIZE = NotImplemented
```

Now if a subclass forgets to override SIZE, the runtime errors will be immediate and obvious.